# SessionState provider sqlConnectionString from another file

Tags: asp.net, .net, security, configuration, web-config

In an ASP.NET project there is a sessionState provider configured in Web.config as follows.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <sessionState>
            <providers>
                <add name="name" sqlConnectionString="secret-stuff" />
            </providers>
        </sessionState>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I don't want to keep my connection strings in source control.For other elements I use the following setup.

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config">
<appSettings file="AppSettingsSecrets.config">
```

The sensitive data is kept in separate files not tracked by git. I am searching for an analogous solution for the sesstionState element.